# Jasmine HTTP request testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

Below is my jasmine test code.

```
const https = require('http');
var base_url = "http://localhost:3000/";

function testAsync(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     https.get(base_url, res => {
    console.log("result is : " + res);
  let data = [];
  const headerDate = res.headers && res.headers.date ? res.headers.date : 'no response date';
  console.log('Status Code:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('Date in Response header:', headerDate);

  res.on('data', chunk => {
      console.log("inside data : " +data);
    data.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on('end', () => {
      console.log("data" + data);
    // console.log('Response ended: ');
    // const users = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(data).toString());

    // for(user of users) {
    //   console.log(`Got user with id: ${user.id}, name: ${user.name}`);
    // }
  });
  resolve();
}).on('error', err => {
  console.log('Error: ', err);
  resolve();
});
});
  }


describe("Hello World Server", function() {

describe("GET /", function() {

it("returns status code 200",  async function() {
console.log("before http get");
await testAsync();
console.log("after http get");
});

});
});
```

when I run it, I get the below error. Could someone help to resolve this error please

---

*LOG: 'before http get'
LOG: 'Error: ', TypeError: Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
at module.exports.ClientRequest._onFinish (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/s7/lslgtwnx2px86cqjhlfynp_w0000gn/T/3e973e3340db6a2c56d8e559cc233f06.browserify.js?9dffcbb6a2ae2b7cbde165353439c6209f6eaf5f:8593:10)
at module.exports. (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/s7/lslgtwnx2px86cqjhlfynp_w0000gn/T/3e973e3340db6a2c56d8e559cc233f06.browserify.js?9dffcbb6a2ae2b7cbde165353439c6209f6eaf5f:8511:8)
at module.exports.emit (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/s7/lslgtwnx2px86cqjhlfynp_w0000gn/T/3e973e3340db6a2c56d8e559cc233f06.browserify.js?9dffcbb6a2ae2b7cbde165353439c6209f6eaf5f:2692:5)
at finishMaybe (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/s7/lslgtwnx2px86cqjhlfynp_w0000gn/T/3e973e3340db6a2c56d8e559cc233f06.browserify.js?9dffcbb6a2ae2b7cbde165353439c6209f6eaf5f:7444:14)
at endWritable (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/s7/lslgtwnx2px86cqjhlfynp_w0000gn/T/3e973e3340db6a2c56d8e559cc233f06.browserify.js?9dffcbb6a2ae2b7cbde165353439c6209f6eaf5f:7463:3)
at module.exports.Writable.end (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/s7/lslgtwnx2px86cqjhlfynp_w0000gn/T/3e973e3340db6a2c56d8e559cc233f06.browserify.js?9dffcbb6a2ae2b7cbde165353439c6209f6eaf5f:7391:22)
at module.exports.ClientRequest.end (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/s7/lslgtwnx2px86cqjhlfynp_w0000gn/T/3e973e3340db6a2c56d8e559cc233f06.browserify.js?9dffcbb6a2ae2b7cbde165353439c6209f6eaf5f:8763:32)
at Object.get (http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/s7/lslgtwnx2px86cqjhlfynp_w0000gn/T/3e973e3340db6a2c56d8e559cc233f06.browserify.js?9dffcbb6a2ae2b7cbde165353439c6209f6eaf5f:8343:6)
at http://localhost:9876/absolute/var/folders/s7/lslgtwnx2px86cqjhlfynp_w0000gn/T/3e973e3340db6a2c56d8e559cc233f06.browserify.js?9dffcbb6a2ae2b7cbde165353439c6209f6eaf5f:10878:13
at new Promise ()
LOG: 'after http get'*

---

Comment: what debugging did you try so far?

Comment: When I run the testAsync function without jasmine it works fine. I'm getting the error only while running it via jasmine

Comment: This error occured when I ran the test via Karma- jasmine. However when I run it using stand alone jasmine it worked. Does anyone know why it doesn't work using karma?